# How do I delete a parent and its children in the adjacency list model?

Tags: mysql, hierarchy, myisam

```
+--------+---------+-----------+
|   id   | title   | parent_id |
+--------+---------+-----------+
|    1   | Lvl-1   |   null    |
+--------+---------+-----------+
|    2   | Lvl-11  |     1     |
+--------+---------+-----------+
|    3   | Lvl-111 |     2     |
+--------+---------+-----------+
|    4   | Lvl-12  |     4     |
+--------+---------+-----------+
```

What I'm trying to do is, when I delete the row with id 1, it will delete all its child rows (the rows with id 2 and 3 in the example table). The row with ID 2 should be deleted because its parent_id is 1, and the row with ID 3 should be deleted because its parent_id is 2.

I'm using the MyISAM engine. Is it possible to delete the row and all child rows with just one query?

Comment: Check out the nested sets model which lends itself to easier SQL operations on hierarchical data.

Comment: @a'r any link on that would be appreciated

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nested_set_model

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, not with myISAM.  If you set this up with constraints in InnoDB, it may work.

But by doing this you're using a table-oriented data store to manage a hierarchical data structure.  You would be wise to handle this kind of thing explicitly in your application program.

Comment: Relying on dbms mechanisms also negatively impacts portability.

Answer (score 1):

<strike>What you need is a `DELETE TRIGGER`, see [12.1.11. CREATE TRIGGER Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-trigger.html) from the MySQL Documentation.</strike>

Triggers can't perform operations on the same table that it's triggering the event on. I'd recommend you either use a scheduled event, create a stored procedure, or you handle it in the application handling the MySQL.

Comment: besides trigger, any other way doing it with pure query?

Comment: I just updated my answer after realizing I was mistaken about the triggers anyway.